# Instantiate Bean/Service with Spring IoC

Tags: java, spring, apple-push-notifications

With Java-APNS, they create a service like this:

```
 ApnsService service = APNS.newService()
     .withCert("C:/temp/myCertificate.p12", "p@ssw0rd")
     .withSandboxDestination()
     .build();
```

ApnsService is a Java Interface.

I'd like to instantiate this service with Spring and inject it in another service, any idea?

Best thanks to you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be able to do it in Spring by designating a factory method in the application context for that bean, but it could be tricky.  The Bloch builder idiom is not what Spring had in mind.

Comment: <bean id="myFactory" 
  class="example.MyClassFactory
  factory-method="getInstance">
  <constructor -arg value="12345"/>
</bean> is what I'm looking for

Comment: Glad it helped.  I was certain about factory, but not the details.